# How to implement composite pattern using room (list of list of items)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I have an Entity like this:

```
@Entity(tableName = "content", indices = [Index(value = ["id"], unique = true)])
open class ContentEntity(
   @PrimaryKey val id: Int,
   val name: String,
   val type: String,
   @ColumnInfo(defaultValue = "-1") val parentId: Int = -1
)
```

and a relation class:

```
data class ContentTaskEntity(
@Embedded val content: ContentEntity,
@Relation(
    parentColumn = "id",
    entityColumn = "parentId",
    entity = ContentEntity::class
)
val contentList: List<ContentEntity>
)
```

My Dao:

```
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM content WHERE parentId == -1")
fun getAllContentTask(): List<ContentTaskEntity>
```

This works fine for a 1 level object (one-to-many):

```
    val contentTask = ContentEntity(1, "Parent", "TASK", -1)
    val contentChild = ContentEntity(2, "Child", "CHILD", 1)
    val contentChild2 = ContentEntity(3, "Child2", "CHILD", 1)
    val contentChild3 = ContentEntity(4, "Child3", "CHILD", 1)
```

When I call getAllContentTask from my Dao, it gives me 1 object with a list of 3 children.

How to make it work for a 2 level object for example (one-one-many):

```
    val contentTask = ContentEntity(1, "Parent", "TASK", -1)
    val contentChild = ContentEntity(2, "ChildWithChild", "CHILDPARENT", 1)
    val contentChild2 = ContentEntity(3, "Child2", "CHILD", 2)
    val contentChild3 = ContentEntity(4, "Child3", "CHILD", 2)
```

This returns me 1 object with a list of 1, but this one HAS NO LIST inside of it. How could I achieve that?

Comment: You mean, an Item will have the object with `id=1` and a list with `id=2` which again will contain the later two items(`id=3` & `id=4`) inside?

Comment: Yes! The composite pattern. One composite can have a list of composite or a leaf. It can have as many lists as desired

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps consider the following.

First a POJO without @Embedded or @Relation **ContentEntityWithAllChildren**

```
data class ContentWithAllChildren(
    var contentEntity: ContentEntity,
    var children: ArrayList<ContentEntity> = ArrayList()
)
```

- So the "Parent" ContentEntity and an Array of all the Children ContentEntities.

and then a function **getAllLowerLevelChildren** to return a ContentWithAllChildren (with a body) as part of the Dao class (the Dao class being an abstract class rather than an interface) e.g. **AllDao** :-

```
@Dao
abstract class AllDao {
    @Insert
    abstract fun insert(contentEntity: ContentEntity): Long
    @Query("DELETE FROM content")
    abstract fun clearContent(): Int
    @Query("SELECT id FROM content WHERE name=:name")
    abstract fun getIdByName(name: String): Long
    @Query("SELECT * FROM content WHERE name=:name")
    abstract fun getContentEntityByName(name: String): ContentEntity
    @Query("SELECT * FROM content WHERE id=:id")
    abstract fun getContentEntityById(id: Long): ContentEntity
    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM content WHERE parentid IN(:parentList)")
    abstract fun getChildren(parentList: List<Long>): List<ContentEntity>


    fun getAllLowerLevelChildren(contentEntity: ContentEntity, maxDepth: Int = 10): ContentWithAllChildren {
        var currentDepth = 0;
        var currentList = getChildren(listOf(contentEntity.id!!))
        var rv = ContentWithAllChildren(contentEntity)
        var idList = ArrayList<Long>()
        while (currentList.isNotEmpty() && currentDepth < maxDepth) {
            currentDepth++
            idList.clear()
            for (ce: ContentEntity in currentList) {
                rv.children.add(ce)
                if (ce.id != null) {
                    idList.add(ce.id)
                }
            }
            currentList = getChildren(idList)
        }
        return rv
    }
}
```

And to demonstrate the following in an activity (.allowMainThreadQueries used for convenience/brevity) :-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var db: TheDatabase
    lateinit var dao: AllDao
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = db.getAllDao()
        Log.d(TAG,"Cleared ${dao.clearContent()} rows.")

        val p1 = dao.insert(ContentEntity(name ="TASK1",type = "PARENT TASK"))
        val c1 = dao.insert(ContentEntity(name = "C1",type = "CHILD",parentId = p1))
        val c2 = dao.insert(ContentEntity(name = "C2",type = "CHILD", parentId = p1))
        val c3 = dao.insert(ContentEntity(name = "C3",type = "CHILD", parentId = dao.insert(ContentEntity(name = "TASK2",type = "TASK"))))
        val c4 = dao.insert(ContentEntity(name = "GC1", type = "GRANDCHILD", parentId = c1))
        val c5 = dao.insert(ContentEntity(name = "GGC1", type = "GREATGRANDCHILD",parentId = c4))
        val c6 = dao.insert(ContentEntity(name = "GGGC1", type = "GREATEGREATGRANDCHILD",parentId = c5))


        logContentEntityWithChildren(dao.getAllLowerLevelChildren(dao.getContentEntityByName("TASK2")))
        logContentEntityWithChildren(dao.getAllLowerLevelChildren(dao.getContentEntityByName("TASK1")))
        // From part way through the hierarchy */
        logContentEntityWithChildren(dao.getAllLowerLevelChildren(dao.getContentEntityByName("GC1")))
        logContentEntityWithChildren(dao.getAllLowerLevelChildren(dao.getContentEntityById(c4)))

    }

    private fun logContentEntityWithChildren(cewac: ContentWithAllChildren) {
        Log.d(TAG,"PARENT is ${cewac.contentEntity.name} " +
                "TYPE is ${cewac.contentEntity.type} " +
                "ID is ${cewac.contentEntity.id} " +
                "PARENT ID is ${cewac.contentEntity.parentId}")
        for(child: ContentEntity in cewac.children) {
            Log.d(TAG,"\tCHILD is ${child.name} TYPE is ${child.type} ID is ${child.id} PARENT ID is ${child.parentId}")
        }
    }

    companion object {
        const val TAG = "DBINFO"
    }
}
```

The first block, after setting the ContentView, gets the Database and the Alldao and then deletes any existing data.

The next block adds some testing data which via Database Inspector is :-

[image]

- So **GGGC1** is 4 levels below **TASK1** (i.e. a GREAT GREAT GRAND CHILD of TASK1 via GGC1, GC1 and C1, TASK 1 also has a second child C2).

The last lines use the **getAllLowerLevelChildren** function to a **ContentEntityWithAllChildren** noting that you can initiate it at any level (as per the last two lines that initiate at level 2 a grandchild).

The Log includes :-

```
2021-10-21 13:28:10.600 D/DBINFO: Cleared 8 rows.
2021-10-21 13:28:10.693 D/DBINFO: PARENT is TASK2 TYPE is TASK ID is 4 PARENT ID is -1
2021-10-21 13:28:10.694 D/DBINFO:   CHILD is C3 TYPE is CHILD ID is 5 PARENT ID is 4

2021-10-21 13:28:10.715 D/DBINFO: PARENT is TASK1 TYPE is PARENT TASK ID is 1 PARENT ID is -1
2021-10-21 13:28:10.716 D/DBINFO:   CHILD is C1 TYPE is CHILD ID is 2 PARENT ID is 1
2021-10-21 13:28:10.716 D/DBINFO:   CHILD is C2 TYPE is CHILD ID is 3 PARENT ID is 1
2021-10-21 13:28:10.716 D/DBINFO:   CHILD is GC1 TYPE is GRANDCHILD ID is 6 PARENT ID is 2
2021-10-21 13:28:10.716 D/DBINFO:   CHILD is GGC1 TYPE is GREATGRANDCHILD ID is 7 PARENT ID is 6
2021-10-21 13:28:10.716 D/DBINFO:   CHILD is GGGC1 TYPE is GREATEGREATGRANDCHILD ID is 8 PARENT ID is 7

2021-10-21 13:28:10.739 D/DBINFO: PARENT is GC1 TYPE is GRANDCHILD ID is 6 PARENT ID is 2
2021-10-21 13:28:10.740 D/DBINFO:   CHILD is GGC1 TYPE is GREATGRANDCHILD ID is 7 PARENT ID is 6
2021-10-21 13:28:10.740 D/DBINFO:   CHILD is GGGC1 TYPE is GREATEGREATGRANDCHILD ID is 8 PARENT ID is 7

2021-10-21 13:28:10.748 D/DBINFO: PARENT is GC1 TYPE is GRANDCHILD ID is 6 PARENT ID is 2
2021-10-21 13:28:10.748 D/DBINFO:   CHILD is GGC1 TYPE is GREATGRANDCHILD ID is 7 PARENT ID is 6
2021-10-21 13:28:10.748 D/DBINFO:   CHILD is GGGC1 TYPE is GREATEGREATGRANDCHILD ID is 8 PARENT ID is 7
```

- **Note** that Longs rather the Ints were used for the ids and parentids as theoretically they can be Long, so a few changes would need to be made to utilise Ints rather then Longs.

**Additional**

Re the comment:-

> I thought there would be some way using ROOM to do a recursive query or something similar that would return the object to me (with their children). Using REALM, for example, I could get the full object with a one line code.

There is a you could utilise a recursive query, it would be something, like:-

```
SELECT * FROM cte1;
WITH
    cte1(id,name,type,parentid) 
        AS (
            SELECT *
            FROM content AS c1 WHERE id = 1 /* VALUE OF TOP MOST */
            UNION ALL 
            SELECT c2.* FROM content AS c2
            JOIN cte1 AS d ON d.id = c2.parentid 
        )
SELECT * FROM cte1;
```

Using the following data :-

[image]

The above (i.e. for TASK1 i.e. ID = 1) would result in :-

[image]

For TASK2 i.e. ID = 10 then the result would be :-

[image]

For C1 i.e. ID = 2 the result would be :-

[image]

**However**

The above gets the data you require BUT how would Room use this (rhetorical)? Each row would be an object. So you probably wouldn't want the parent included. As you want the parent with it's children.

So you would probably want the query to be :-

```
WITH
    cte_parameter(parm1) AS (SELECT 1/* VALUE OF TOP MOST */),
    cte1(id,name,type,parentid) 
        AS (
            SELECT *
            FROM content AS c1 WHERE id = (SELECT parm1 FROM cte_parameter) /* VALUE OF TOP MOST */
            UNION ALL 
            SELECT c2.* FROM content AS c2
            JOIN cte1 AS d ON d.id = c2.parentid 
        )
SELECT * FROM cte1  WHERE id <> (SELECT parm1 FROM cte_parameter);
```

i.e. you don't want the row for the passed ID so that is excluded by the additional WHERE clause at the end, using the same value as passed (could be coded and replaced).

The output for ID 1 then becomes :-

[image]

Putting this into action then the following is added to **AllDao** :-

```
@Query("WITH p(parm1) AS (SELECT :id), " +
        "cte1(id,name,type,parentId) AS(SELECT * FROM content AS c1 WHERE id=(SELECT parm1 FROM p) " +
        "UNION ALL " +
        "SELECT c2.* FROM content AS c2 JOIN cte1 AS d ON d.id = c2.parentId) " +
        "SELECT * FROM cte1 WHERE id <> (SELECT parm1 FROM p);")
abstract fun getContentEntityChildren(id: Long): List<ContentEntity>

fun buildContentEntityWithAllChildren(contentEntity: ContentEntity): ContentWithAllChildren {
    return ContentWithAllChildren(contentEntity,getContentEntityChildren(contentEntity.id!!).toCollection(ArrayList()))
}
```

And the following is added to **MainActivity** (i.e. the equivalent of the previous examples) :-

```
    Log.d(TAG,"VIA RECURSIVE QUERY")
    logContentEntityWithChildren(dao.buildContentEntityWithAllChildren(dao.getContentEntityByName("TASK1")))
    logContentEntityWithChildren(dao.buildContentEntityWithAllChildren(dao.getContentEntityByName("TASK2")))
    logContentEntityWithChildren(dao.buildContentEntityWithAllChildren(dao.getContentEntityByName("GC1")))
    logContentEntityWithChildren(dao.buildContentEntityWithAllChildren(dao.getContentEntityById(c4)))
```

And the resultant (additional) output to the log is :-

```
2021-10-22 13:01:17.940 D/DBINFO: VIA RECURSIVE QUERY
2021-10-22 13:01:17.961 D/DBINFO: PARENT is TASK1 TYPE is PARENT TASK ID is 1 PARENT ID is -1
2021-10-22 13:01:17.961 D/DBINFO:   CHILD is C1 TYPE is CHILD ID is 2 PARENT ID is 1
2021-10-22 13:01:17.961 D/DBINFO:   CHILD is C2 TYPE is CHILD ID is 3 PARENT ID is 1
2021-10-22 13:01:17.961 D/DBINFO:   CHILD is GC1 TYPE is GRANDCHILD ID is 6 PARENT ID is 2
2021-10-22 13:01:17.961 D/DBINFO:   CHILD is GGC1 TYPE is GREATGRANDCHILD ID is 7 PARENT ID is 6
2021-10-22 13:01:17.962 D/DBINFO:   CHILD is GGGC1 TYPE is GREATEGREATGRANDCHILD ID is 8 PARENT ID is 7
2021-10-22 13:01:17.965 D/DBINFO: PARENT is TASK2 TYPE is TASK ID is 4 PARENT ID is -1
2021-10-22 13:01:17.965 D/DBINFO:   CHILD is C3 TYPE is CHILD ID is 5 PARENT ID is 4
2021-10-22 13:01:17.967 D/DBINFO: PARENT is GC1 TYPE is GRANDCHILD ID is 6 PARENT ID is 2
2021-10-22 13:01:17.968 D/DBINFO:   CHILD is GGC1 TYPE is GREATGRANDCHILD ID is 7 PARENT ID is 6
2021-10-22 13:01:17.968 D/DBINFO:   CHILD is GGGC1 TYPE is GREATEGREATGRANDCHILD ID is 8 PARENT ID is 7
2021-10-22 13:01:17.971 D/DBINFO: PARENT is GC1 TYPE is GRANDCHILD ID is 6 PARENT ID is 2
2021-10-22 13:01:17.971 D/DBINFO:   CHILD is GGC1 TYPE is GREATGRANDCHILD ID is 7 PARENT ID is 6
2021-10-22 13:01:17.971 D/DBINFO:   CHILD is GGGC1 TYPE is GREATEGREATGRANDCHILD ID is 8 PARENT ID is 7
```

Comment: Tks @MikeT,  this works. I thought there would be some way using ROOM to do a recursive query or something similar that would return the object to me (with their children). Using REALM, for example, I could get the full object with a one line code.

Comment: @user2494863 add a recursive query equivalent.